# Compact SCALE decoding

Tags: scale

In this [answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2706/2132) the compact decoding for 1 byte and multi-byte versions have been detailed. I [did a sample implementation](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2819/2132) based on that information and it does what it is supposed to, at least for the specific usecase. (My toy obviously has holes, but it is more for my understanding as opposed to be production hardened)

However, the original answer didn't quite detail the decoding of the `0b01` and `0b10` flags as the last 2 bits of a compact first byte, based on that I have a gap in my knowledge which I really want to close out.

I would appreciate a full run-through answer, basically a "this is how to decode all compact numbers (for dummies)".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a description of [SCALE compact-encoding](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/scale-codec/). As you mentioned in your question, there are basically 4 variants indicated by the flags from the 2 least-significant bits.

Effectively when decoding the first byte of SCALE compact, it would be in the form `0bxxxxxxyy` where `yy` are the flags and the most-significant 6 `xxxxxx` are the bits containing the value in the first byte.

Interpreting the lest-significant binary flags you can have lengths of 1, 2, 4 & 4+ bytes -

`00` This is a single-byte version. To extract the value, you would do `byte1 >> 2`. As an example `0b00000100` would be `4 >> 2 = 1`

`01` This is a double-byte version. To extract the value, you would do `(byte1 + (byte2 << 8)) >> 2`. As an example `0b11111101 0b00000111` would be `(253 + (7 << 8)) >> 2 = 511`

`10` This is the 4 byte version. For extracting the value, it ends up being `(byte1 + (byte2 << 8) + (byte3 << 16) + (byte4 << 24)) >> 2`. An example would be `0b11111110 0b11111111 0b11111111 0b11111111` which would be `(254 + (255 << 8) + (255 << 16) + (255 << 24)) >> 2 = 1073741823`

`11` This is the n-byte version. The first byte + 4 details the number of bytes following. So Assuming a first byte of `0b00000111` it would yield 5 bytes, i.e. `(7 >> 2) + 4 = 5`. The next 5 bytes would therefore be the LE encoded value.

Depending on your toolset and language, be aware that some of these are very large numbers and could overflow the "normal" representation. So it is recommended to use big integer support for your environment especially when converting the very large values.

(And example of this is JS where the [maximum integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) is 2^53 - 1. So in this specific case you may want to use [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) or alternatives when converting. Other languages would have other limits, bear those in mind.)